# Bug in TexDef: Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated

Tags: perl, texdef

I've been encountering some warnings when using `texdef` lately. Of course, the command itself works brilliantly.

Running the command : `texdef TeX` produces this error-message:

```
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\\\@protected\@testopt { <-- HERE ?\\.*? }? *(\\\\.*?) / at /usr/local/bin/texdef line 391.
Unescaped left brace in regex is deprecated, passed through in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^\\\@testopt { <-- HERE ?(\\.*?) }?/ at /usr/local/bin/texdef line 394.
```

If I am not mistaken, this is related to PERL.

Is this something that is happening on only my computer, or for everybody?

I am running MacOSX El Capitan, `texdef` version 1.7b, `perl` version v5.22.1

Comment: I too noticed the same defect after installing Perl 5.24 with Homebrew. It doesn't show with the default Perl in Mac OS X 10.11, though, AFAIR.

Comment: This is similar to [a bug that occurred with makeglossaries](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/bugtracker.cgi?action=view&key=101). Newer versions of Perl require escaped `\{` and `\}` in regular expressions instead of unescaped `{` and `}`. This needs correcting in the given line numbers at the end of each warning.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue has long been solved with a new version of texdef

Comment: @egreg Not everyone will have the update.  My own TeX version predates the year this question was posted.  There will be some who still encounter the issue, and upgrading is not always an option.

Comment: @Polyhat Closing doesn't mean deleting.

Comment: @egreg I appreciate that, but does it not mean that no further answers would be accepted here?  Perhaps someone can more eloquently detail a solution than is already posted.  The answer I provided focuses more on understanding the Perl, which was only part of the question.  As I don't have MacOSX El Capitan (I have Mountain Lion, which is an earlier version), I have left the intricacies of the TexDef on that OS to others.

Answer (score 0):

Unescaped curly braces are special characters in a Perl regex that indicate the number of the prior character, expression, or captured group to match.  For example, `s/h{2}/h/g;` would be a substitution expression that would replace every doubled "h" character with a single one.  In order to clarify to Perl that your curly braces are not to be considered in this way, but to be matched as literal characters, you will need to escape them with a backslash.